# Appium Python sun/misc/BASE64Encoder

Tags: android, python, testing, appium

i try to test my mobile application with Appium.
I wrote a function test in python.
When i run the test i have this error.

> in setup at line :  self.driver = webdriver.Remote(xxxx)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder

the size of the apk past xxK0 to 0ko ???

Answer (score 0):

Without code sample there is no much help you can get. Take a look at [official code samples](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/python/android_simple.py) in `python` and make sure you run setup server and capabilities in a proper way

Comment: I try : /n 1- your sample with my app Path, the result is the same. /n  2-your sample with your app, it done.... i think my app is not correctly build